# How to draw using framebuffer on Android?

Tags: android, c, linux, graphics, framebuffer

I would like to write an application for Android which displays stuff on screen using the framebuffer.  This will run only on a specific rooted device, so permissions etc is not a problem.  Same application (simple test version anyway) is already running okay on PC/Linux.

The questions:

1. How to avoid the Android OS from accessing the framebuffer?  I would like, while my application is running, to have the OS *never* touch the framebuffer, no writes and no ioctls.  What do I need to do to get exclusive use of the framebuffer, and then (when my application quits) give it back to the OS?
2. Are there any differences between Android framebuffer and Linux framebuffer to watch out for?

P.S. I would like to start my application as a regular Android application (with some native code), it just has no visible UI except for framebuffer draws which take over the whole screen.  It would be nice to still be able to get events from the OS.

See also:
http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/display_drivers.html

Answer (score 6):

Hi Alex Not sure  why  / how to  stop android OS  from writing to framebuffer. As long as your android application is visible and on top   you have the control as what you want to display.

Your application should have an activity with a  SurfaceView ( you may want your application to hide notification bar call this function in oncreate of your activity)
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` )

your activity  should have  **SurfaceHolder.Callback** implementation to  handle  callbacks as  when the surface is ready to  filled with framebuffer. Get the surface holder object as SurfaceView.getHolder() incase  you want  set pixel formats of the view  etc.

Once "**surfaceCreated**" callback is called  you can safely  pass  your surfaceview object(passing width and height maybe a good idea too) to the native so that you can  fill it  framebuffer using "ANativeWindow"  class.

Check  NDK sample code to see how to  use the class [NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

[SurfaceHolder.Callback documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html)

[SurfaceHolder documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html)

essentially you need to these (ON JB /Kitkat)

1. get the native window (ANativeWindow) associated with the surfaceview  by `ANativeWindow_fromSurface`.
2. Acquire a lock on the ANativeWindow by `ANativeWindow_acquire` .
3. Set  geometry parameters(window,width,height,pf) for the nativewindow by `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry`
4. Load the nativewindow with the  frambuffer stored (apply dirty rectangle if any here)
   by `ANativeWindow_lock`
5. Final  step to unlock and post the  changes for rendering by `ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost`

Go through the  ndk sample examples in case you need sample code.[NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, but your answer does not actually say anything about framebuffer :(  I know about ANativeWindow.  Problem is that the buffers that you can get from it are still handled by the compositor, they are double/triple buffered and (I believe) may sometimes also be composited using OpenGL draws.  In any case there is substantial delay between that and actually seeing pixels on screen (several frames).  I want to go one layer down, to whatever Android is using as the last step in the compositor before displaying stuff.  I especially want non-double-buffered draws.  Thoughts?

Comment: you are  correct  these  writes  are still  double  or  triple  buffered (JB onwards) . I dont see a  way to avoid that without changing  a  lot of surface flinger code. Also it  may lead to  buffer  corruption at times  when other  system apps / notification tries to  write to  buffer  if  such a buffer  circumvented.

Comment: yes, that's it. I want not to change surface flinger, but just turn it off, and use the fb device directly.  and I also want to disable system apps/notification/anything else that may try to draw (although, usually I suppose if they draw it would only stay around for one frame).

Comment: not sure how to turn off surface flinger or bypass it .. sorry.